# App displaying in landscape when on iPhone mode on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, screen-orientation

When my app launches on the iPhone, it displays in portrait, as it should. When it launches on the iPad in iPhone mode, it displays in landscape, if rotated that way. This is the code I have:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Set the supported orientation inside Project Settings in Summary section to portrait only

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 6, have you try :

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your project info.plist file, remove the landscape flags from supported orientations list.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode select one of your target then under summary tab make sure you have selected only UIpotrait orientation and rest all of them are unslected, then choose info tab and see that under "supported interface orientations" row it should have only UIpotrait orientation .Now open your delegate file and for ios5 this method works

`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}`

but this method is deprecated for iOS6 to override it for iOS6

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

```
return YES;
```

}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
```

}
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
```

}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
```

}